# Zend Service Amazon S3 doesn't create a bucket and anything. what's wrong? - Zend Framework 2.3.4

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zend-framework2

I tried to create bucket with Zend Service\Amazon\S3 after installing with composer.

[Zend Framework Amazon Service S3 Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zendservice.amazon.s3.html)

this is my code:

```
  $my_aws_key = '**********';
  $my_aws_secret_key =  '******************';
 $s3 = new ZendService\Amazon\S3\S3($my_aws_key, $my_aws_secret_key);
 $s3->createBucket('name-bucket-is-secret', 'eu-central-1');
```

the aws and secret aws key's values are correct and active, the class is called correctly and don't display any error, but when I check the buckets into S3's console, there aren't any buckets! This code doesn't nothing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ([Issue #41](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Amazon/issues/41)), with error 403 using Zend Amazon Service for S3, find out the error was wrong date format from Zend.

Solution:

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Amazon/pull/49